# xsl template brings unexpected results with public Italian Trusted Lists EIDAS XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to apply a really trivial XSL template to this [XML](https://eidas.agid.gov.it/TL/TSL-IT.xml), which is basically an official list of Trusted Service Providers from the Italian government.

I expect this XML has nothing wrong with it.

I would like to extract from this XML, a sub-list of TrustServiceProvider, from the following element

> /TrustServiceStatusList/TrustServiceProviderList/

so I tried to apply something like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="TrustServiceStatusList/TrustServiceProviderList/TrustServiceProvider">
                <xsl:if test="true">
                    <xsl:value-of select="TSPInformation/TSPName/Name"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:if>                   
        </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and expected this to output all names of the TrustServiceProvider elements, except that it doesn't. The only output is the first line of the XSL template.

Does anyone have a clue about what is going on here??

Comment: Perhaps add a sample of input XML and your desired actual output

Comment: Input XML is in form of hyperlink in the post. This is the link https://eidas.agid.gov.it/TL/TSL-IT.xml. my expected output would just be a list of names, nothing more.

Comment: Next time, please post a [mcve] within your question, not 27k lines of code in external link.